# CMS Strapi issue with warning "bad request"

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi

Strapi CMS In Dashboard iam not able do anything like save the Contant or delete the contant for ex. if i add any contant to any element when i press save button its giving warning the "Bad request" warning it was gving even in dashboard iam not able give the setting roles public permission.

In server its not showing any errors also if i trying to edit ant thing in strapi dashboard its giving warning bad request. In try in run develop mood also but still its not giving any access to edit any thing.

Comment: your question is not clear man! please ask something that the community understands, I hope that helps